# Text won't align or move

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="background"></div>
  <div id="dialog">
        <p>Hello there!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="button" onclick="showDialog()">
        <img src="images/images/sceond3.jpg" width="126" height="210" alt=""/>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

var counter = 0;
function showDialog() {
    if (counter == 0) {
        $("#dialog p").html("Testing Second Line!");
    }
    if (counter == 1) {
        $("#dialog p").html("Testing Third Line!");
    }
    //increase counter by 1
    counter++;
}

</script>
</html>


body {
    line-height:0;
}

#container {
    float: left;
    height: 630px;
    width: 1155px;
}

#background {
    background-image: url(images/images/second1.jpg);
    float: left;
    height: 420px;
    width: 1155px;
}

#dialog {
    background-image: url(images/images/second2.jpg);
    z-index: 100;
    float: left;
    height: 210px;
    width: 1029px;
    left: 70px;
    top: 618px;
    font-size:25px;
}
```

Hello there, I'm having problem aligning and moving text in my HTML code. Basically, I have some text in my dialog div, however, no matter what I do to that div in CSS, the text doesn't seem to want to move or anything.

I would appreciate any help at all. Thank you.

Comment: have you tried setting position:absolute?

Comment: Have you tried adding `text-align: left;` to your dialogue div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dialog div is the container for your text. If you want to align the text itself within the container, which is in the 'p' tag, you'll need to apply css to "#dialog p". This will let you center it within the dialog div. You can then change the width and positioning of the dialog div as needed.

```
#dialog p {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: The `text-align` doesn't need to be in a separate style. It can go right in the #dialog. For example: https://jsfiddle.net/2a1mt3dm/

Comment: That's true, however I'm focusing on the text since that's all that was mentioned, and there may eventually be other elements like images in the div that they may not want centered.

Comment: Well that's good. It's better to have it structured that way, but in the answer you're saying that it's part of the issue, which it's not.

Comment: Worked for me :) Using #dialog p {} I could apply any css style to it and it worked, thank you so much!

Comment: Or you could just change the text-align property during method invocation : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/6d5ry9br/2/

Comment: That wouldn't apply to the initial text before it's clicked once.